Permutative Gray monoid that can not be strictified
 Strict monoidal 2-categories do not suffice to model all connected 3-types: the non-trivial coherence cells $\Sigma: (f \otimes 1)\circ (1 \otimes g) \cong (1 \otimes g)\circ (f \otimes 1) $ of a Gray monoid are necessary to model a generally non-trivial Whitehead product (see Chapter 4 of Simpson ) $$\pi_2 \times \pi_2 \to \pi_3$$ 
For the 'standard' realization functor  $\mathcal{R}$, the argument in Simpson boils down to the fact that  $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{C})$ of a 1-connected strict 3-groupoid $\mathcal{C}$ is always a loop space. However, for loop spaces, the Whitehead product vanishes, thus proving that $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{C})$ cannot model any 1-connected space with non-trivial Whitehead products. In particular, it is not possible to model the 3-truncation of $S^2$, using only the data of a strict monoidal 2-groupoid. 
Similarly, while every monoidal bicategory is (categorical) equivalent to a Gray monoid, in general we cannot strictify further down to strict monoidal 2-categories. This is just the non-groupoid version of the above.  
I would like to understand the corresponding situation in the presence of a symmetric structure. It seems to be generally known (see Gurski-Johnson-Osorno/2/Rem.6.29) that permutative Gray monoids too cannot be strictified further to permutative 2-categories. Indeed, in Schommer-Pries/Example.2.30. a permutative Gray monoid $\equiv \mathcal{D}$ is defined, which is not biequivalent to any permutative 2-category. However, this statement is not proven. Instead, it is referred to Chapter 4 of Simpson which is the argument for (non-symmetric) monoidal 2-groupoids, as I explained above.
My confusion lies in the following observation: The classifying space of a symmetric monoidal bicategory automatically inherits an $E_\infty$-structure. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is actually a strict Picard groupoid (all cells are invertible), it seems to me that $\mathcal{R}(D)$ is an infinite loop space and thus has vanishing Whitehead products. In particular, I do not see how the argument in Simpson can be used to verify that $\mathcal{D}$ cannot be equivalent to any permutative 2-category. 
Note also a result by Gurski-Johnson-Osorno/2 (Thm.6.44), which proves that we have an equivalence of homotopy theories:
 $$(Perm2Cat, W) \simeq (PermGrayMon,W)$$ 

$(Perm2Cat,W)$, the relative category of permutative 2-categories and weak
equivalences (equivalence of classifying spaces)
$(PermGrayMon, W)$, the relative category of permutative Gray monoids and weak
equivalences

That is, if we are considering only weak homotopy types, it is indeed true that permutative Gray monoids are modeled by permutative 2-categories. The underlying reasoning why this fails for categorical equivalences is not clear to me.
Edit:
It seems to me that I messed up different notions of realization functors. If we view a Gray monoid $\mathcal{C}$ as a one-object Gray-category, we also have to take a tricategorical realization. This is different from considering $\mathcal{C}$ as a 2-category with extra structure, which upon realization transfers to extra structure on the classifying space. I guess otherwise also Gray monoids would not be able to model all connected homotopy 3-types (then the classifying space would have an $A_\infty$-structure, still implying trivial Whitehead products). I would be happy to hear some thoughts on these considerations and if they make any sense.
